# How to increase size of view(automatically) if the size of text increases in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am making a `UI` design in react native i have made a card of categories i want to increase the width of view if category name is long. but i am not understanding how to do that.Please help here is my code.

```
 <View style={styles.CardMainView}>
   <View style={styles.ThirdLayerStyle} />
   <View style={styles.SecondLayerStyle} />
     <View style={styles.FirstLayerStyle}>
       <Image resizeMode={'contain'} style={styles.CatImageStyle}
         source={require('../../Assets/Images/doccatImage.png')}
       />
     </View>
     <Text numberOfLines={1} style={{color:'#fff' ,  fontSize:15, top:28  , marginLeft:25  , marginRight:20, fontFamily: "poppinsregular"}}>Orthopaedic</Text>
   </View>
 </View>

  CardMainView:{
    flexDirection:'row',
    borderRadius:4,
    backgroundColor:"#1abc9c",
    width:190,
    height:80,
    elevation:3,
    shadowColor:'#000',
    overflow:'hidden',
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

if you do not set width for component, that component can be resizable if the content size change.
also, I write a component which expands on height if the text size increased.
set `height: 0` on state
and add this function to class for focusing on text input

```
focus () {
    this.textInput && this.textInput.focus()
  }
```

and add this component to return

```
<TextInput
        {...this.props}
        ref={(view) => (this.textInput = view)}
        multiline
        onContentSizeChange={(event) => {
          if (event && event.nativeEvent && event.nativeEvent.contentSize) {
            this.setState({
              height: event.nativeEvent.contentSize.height
            })
          }
          this.props.onContentSizeChange && this.props.onContentSizeChange(event)
        }}
        style={[this.props.style, { height: Math.max(35, this.state.height) }]}
      />
```

hopefully, this can help you or get an idea ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can control your size with give a padding innermost component, when you give a padding your component will increase with your text size.